# Android FTP error - 425 Can't open data connection

Tags: android, ftp

I'm using this to upload some file. It works if I in a local connection, but if I use a external connection, i get this message: `425 Can't open data connection.` from the ftp server.

I use the org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient and org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile libs.

```
public static String gravaImagem(String photoFile) {
    FTPClient mFtp = new FTPClient();
    try {
    mFtp.connect(FTPHOST, PORTA);
    mFtp.login(USUARIO, SENHA);
    mFtp.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    mFtp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    String origem = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator+"Pictures"+File.separator+"ImageSec"+File.separator+photoFile;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(origem);
    mFtp.storeFile(photoFile, fis);
    mFtp.logout();
    mFtp.disconnect();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "Fail. (ERR#CON3)";
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "Fail. (ERR#CON4)";
    }
    return "Imagem enviada ao servidor.";
}
```

Debug shows no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

From the internet:

> First - the most common solution:  change the active/passive mode
>   settings.  But that might not work, and if it does its only a band-aid
>   covering up the real problem.
>
> As I've mentioned in the past, one of the most common reasons that
>   this error occurs is a misconfiguration of the FTP server software
>   itself, related to SSL connections and firewalls, in which the
>   connection tries to establish itself on a bogus ip address.  Read more
>   about FTP SSL through a NAT firewall here, some potential solutions
>   are included.
>
> There are other less likely causes, such as:
>
> - The server is configured to always use the same port for passive mode    connections, or the client is configured to always use the
>     same port    for active mode connections, although in this case
>     usually the    software in question should raise a different error
>     first, but I've    seen this happen.
> - In passive mode, the firewall in front of the FTP server doesn't have    the correct ports open.  So the server tells the client to
>     connect to    ipaddress 1.2.3.4 on port x, but the firewall doesn't
>     allow incoming    connections on port x.  Most firewalls are smart
>     enough to open up    the port when it sees the PASV response.  Vice
>     versa for active mode    and the firewall in front of the FTP client.

From me:
 I've used this library on andoird and it worked well, so see my copy/paste section.